# Shortcut keys to view entire git commit history to repo?

Tags: git, github, revision-history

I have 10 commits on a repo for a single file, is there a fast / easy way of browsing through all the deletions / additions using a shortcut key?

As of now I have to click through the repos history → click every file manually to see the commit history

Does github have short keys like arrow keys → ← ↑↓ for moving from one commit history page on master branch to the next commit?

Example diagram workflow:

[image]

I feel like this exists already

Comment: Why not you clone the repository and use command line? git history command to surf through the repos commits

Comment: I didn't think about it but yea that's definitely an option. Was just wondering if github or any extensions had something built for this purpose. What command line arguments would I use after I clone repo though?

Comment: You could try "git log" command.

Comment: But if you want to have a GUI one installed in your system that can assist in examining the history go for

Git-gui
or
GitX (http://gitx.frim.nl/seeit.html)

Answer (score 1):

I will list a few option you could try after cloning the git repo in your system

**Command line Options:**

- git log

**UI based Options:**

- GitX
- Git Bash
- [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/download/)

[REF: GUI list for all platforms](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

Answer (score 1):

For this I'd use:

```
gitk [filename]
```

or to follow filename past renames

```
gitk --follow [filename]
```

You can use

git log -p filename
to let git generate the patches for each log entry.

See

```
git help log
```

for more options - it can actually do a lot of nice things :) To get just the diff for a specific commit you can

```
git show HEAD
```

or any other revision by identifier. Or use

```
gitk
```

to browse the changes visually.

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseGit, you can do:

1. Open a log for a file. (Right click on a file and Show log)

   [image]
2. Enable the **View Patch**

   [image]
3. Then, you get a patch viewer side by side for selected commit

   [image]
4. Using up/down arrow to navigate the commit list and that patch viewer will update automatically. For example, using down arrow:

   [image]